# I have an unusual error while using DevComponets.DotNetBar2.dll in C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms

i have been using DevComponets.DotNetBar2.dll for a while now, and this error has randomly started popping up whenever i try and open another form running DevComponets.DotNetBar.Office2007Form:
"Unable to cast object of type 'TheFallenDeveloper.main' to type 'DevComponents.DotNetBar.Office2007Form'"

As you can see, my namespace is TheFallenDeveloper and the form is main. I was wondering if anyone has experienced this also, and if you had any help to try and fix the error. Other information is as follows:
I am opening a form called Form2 which is also using the Office2007Form
I am opening it from a button
This is the first time it has happened to me, but it doesn't allow me to open the next form

Please help if you can :)

Comment: Maybe the sourcecode line where the cast fails?

Comment: The sourcecode line in which it fails is the 'Application.Run(new Form1());' in Program.cs

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to change your `main` form class to inherit `Office2007Form`.